# Ganapati Shodasa Nama Stotram source

Tags: scripture, puranas, ganesha, stotra

> Sumukhaschaikadanthascha, Kapilo Gaja Karnika,
>
> Lambhodarascha Vikato Vignarajo Vinayaka
>
> Dhoomakethurganadhyaksha Phalachandro Gajanana,
>
> Vakra Thunda Soorpakarno Herambha Skanda poorvaja
>
> Shodasaithani namani ya padeth srunuyadhapi,
>
> Vidhyarambhe vivahe cha pravese, nirgame thadha,
>
> Sangrame sarvakarye cha vigna sthasya na jayathe

This stotra is about the 16 names of Lord Ganesha along with phala shruti.  This stotra is supposed to be from the 24th Prakarana of Upasana Khanda of Ganesa Purana.

Source: http://www.celextel.org/stotras/ganesha/ganapatishodasastotram.html

In the above link it is given that the stotra is from Ganesha purana but it's not.  There is a hint in the below document at page 21 that the stotra might be from Skanda purana

http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/books/ESSENCE%20OF%20GANESHA%20MAHIMA.pdf

If anyone happens to know where exactly in Skanda purana the stotra is mentioned, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This stotra is from Mudgal Puran and known as Ganesh Dwadashanaama Stotra. However the last 4 names are not mentioned and there are some minor changes such as 'Bhaalchandro' instead of 'Phalachandro' etc.

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_ganesha/gaNeshdvAdashanAmastotram.pdf

The last name Skanda poorvaja also does not tally with a Kartikeya Stotra '.... sharajanmaa gaNadhIshapUrvajo....'

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_subrahmanya/skanda.pdf